Setuid bit doesn't work?
I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and trying to run a command as root, but without using sudo and instead using the sticky bit.
I've read this answer but can't seem to get it to work.
I've created a script called whoami_root to show the user that it is running as.
Output of cat whoami_root:
#!/bin/bash
whoami

I have run sudo chown root whoami_root and sudo chmod u+s whoami_root
Output of ll whoami_root:
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 20 Nov  6 23:33 whoami_root

Output of ./whoami_root
myuser

Why does it seem to ignore the suid bit and run as myuser instead of root?

see Why does setuid mode S seem to work for non-owners on a script?

This question is similar to: SUID not working?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The setuid bit is ignored for interpreted programs like shell scripts.
See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/330217
If whoami is a binary executable, you can create a copy of this program and set the setuid bit.

You can configure sudo to allow running a specific command as root without asking for a password.
